# Microservices: API Call Vs Messaging. When to Use?

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, microservices, message-queue, messaging

I know that messaging system is non blocking and scalable and should be used in microservices environment.

The use case that i am questioning is:

Imagine that there's an admin dashboard client responsible for sending API request to create an Item object. There is a microservice that provides API endpoint which uses a MySQL database where the Item should be stored. There is another microservice which uses elastic search for text searching purposes.

Should this admin dashboard client :

A.  Send 2 API Calls; 1 Call to MySQL service and another elasticsearch service

or

B. Send message to topic to be consumed by both MySQL service and elasticsearch service?

What are the pros and cons when considering A or B?

I'm thinking that it's a little overkill when only 2 microservices are consuming this topic. Also, the frequency of which the admin is creating Item object is very small.

Comment: Go for the second approach, as queues have their own pro's also they're fault-tolerant, so your messages aren't lost.

Comment: Option C: you could write the transaction to the database, then use CDC to read the event to a Kafka topic, and then into Elasticsearch

Comment: @robot_alien approach A, both services need to be up and posting a new item will be synchronous both mysql and es. So no message will be lost for approach A too, but i know it tightly couples the services together...it sounds bad but i think its ok for this case?

Comment: @cricket_007 ive also considered this, i looked up tool called monstache that syncs up data in mongodb and elasticsearch, but i dont know, it just seems overkill when compared to just sending a post api call to each ms?

Comment: There is no right and wrong in this case but better approach. You already have answered your question. Approach B is scaleable and non-blocking and in future more services can be added. Approach A is Just better monolith. But in case of (any)service failures Approach B is not going to work. Really depends on you. . In Approach A If your any of the dependent service(s) is down you will be holding off requests and eventually timeout. There is dependency in Approach A so we can't call them true Microservices

Answer (score 5):

Like many things in software architecture, **it depends**. Your requirements, SLAs and business needs should make it clearer.

As you noted, messaging system is not blocking and much more scalable, but, API communication got it pluses as well.

In general, REST APIs are best suited to request/response interactions where the client application sends a request to the API backend over HTTP.

Message streaming is best suited for notifications when new data or events occur that you may want to take action upon.

In you specific case, I would go with a messaging system with is much more scalable and non-blocking.

Answer (score -1):

Your A approach is coupling the "routing" logic into your application. Pretend you need to perform an API call to audit your requests, then you will need to change the code and add another call to your application logic. As you said, the approach is synchronous and unless you're not providing threading logic, your calls will be lined up and won't scale, ie, call mysql --> wait response, then call elastic search --> wait response, ...
In any case you can prefer this approach if you need immediate consistency, ie, the result call of one action feeding the second action.

The B approach is decoupling that routing logic, so, any other service interested in the event can subscribe to the topic and perform the action expected. Totally asynchronous and scalable. Here you will have eventual consistency and you have to recover any possible failure.

Comment: yes so i am actually asking this because of the use case: only like a hundred requests a day, and there will only be 2 consumers for approach B. Given this condition would it be wise to break convention and go for approach A?

Comment: As another comment pointed out, there is no good or bad approach, it just depends on the context, and you are the one knowing it. Technically speaking with approach A you're adding more dependency, but you can proceed with that architecture and change as soon as you have other requirements.